# ORMLite and ListView

Tags: android, listview, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite and I want to display data in a listView, for example, I have a List of SMS (id, number, message) so when I do a query for all I have all of my data and now I want to do a view to display each data, so I found how to do a listView but I don't know how to display the number and the message on each row...

```
public class SMSActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lview;
    SMSAdapter lviewAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);



        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        Dao<SMS, Integer> SMSDao = null;

        try {
            SMSDao = db.getSMSDao();
            final List<SMS> users = SMSDao.queryForAll();
            Log.d("list", users.toString());


            lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

            lviewAdapter = new SMSAdapter(this, ?, ?);

            System.out.println("adapter => "+lviewAdapter.getCount());

            lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

SMSAdapter:

```
public class SMSAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity context;
    String title[];
    String description[];

    public SMSAdapter(Activity context, String[] title, String[] description) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return title.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtViewTitle;
        TextView txtViewDescription;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_sms, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
        holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, i would suggest that you use RecyclerView instead of ListView. Second, also my suggestion is to pass whole list of users in the adapter. 
I think you would like to do this:

```
//...
lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
    SMS sms = users.get(i);
    messages.add(sms.getMessage());
    numbers.add(sms.getNumber());
}
lviewAdapter = new SMSAdapter(this, numbers, messages);
System.out.println("adapter => "+lviewAdapter.getCount());

lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);
//...
```

Your adapter requires two arrays of strings and you can get them from the users list.

Comment: I have to change the adapter because I use: String[] no ?

Comment: I don't see how to change de SMSAdapter

Comment: It's ok I did some changes on my adapter

Comment: You don't have to change the adapter (i just suggested it). The solution i provided is without changing the adapter. Happy coding :)